# XSD to JavaScript class conversion

Tags: javascript, .net, oop, xsd, jsonix

With XSD.exe I can easily derive a C# or VB.NET class from a XSD file. Is there a tool available to convert XSD to JavaScript?

Comment: I think it is less necessary to do something like this for a weakly-typed language.

Answer (score 5):

- Try `xsd /language:JS` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).
- Try [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix), an open-source library for XML<->JS conversion.

With Jsonix you can compile your schema into JavaScript mappings and then marshall/unmarshall XML in your JavaScript code. Here's an example:

```
// First we construct a Jsonix context - a factory for unmarshaller (parser)
// and marshaller (serializer)
var context = new Jsonix.Context([ PO ]);

// Then we create an unmarshaller
var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

// Unmarshal an object from the XML retrieved from the URL
unmarshaller.unmarshalURL('/org/hisrc/jsonix/samples/po/test/po-0.xml',
    // This callback function will be provided with the result
    // of the unmarshalling
    function(result) {
        // We just check that we get the values we expect
        assertEquals('Alice Smith', result.value.shipTo.name);
        assertEquals('Baby Monitor', result.value.item[1].productName);
    });
```

Comment: lexicore: thanks for the tip. I have tried xsd with the "JS" option, the syntax is a different to JavaScript with the private declarations etc. I haven't tried Jsonix, will try this